# Can I change the proportional editing area of influence aspect ratio?

Tags: proportional-editing

I know we can change the size, fall of, etc.

But can I change it from a sphere (or circle in a plane) to an ellipse (Imagine the blue elipse)?

[image]

Comment: You can do something like that with the sculpt brush if you scale the object in object mode, but AFAIK it's not possible with this tool since it's in edit mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is currently no such functionality for proportional editing in Blender.

Comment: Oh, well. That could be an interesting feature tho.